# How to create service that handles keyDown, keyUp action from physical keyboard for any android application?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-service

How handle key actions from bluetooth physical keyboard for any application? I read articles about custom soft keyboard but i have bluetooth physical keyboard and i want to create some custom keyboard soft app that handles key actions from keyboard for any application; What should i do for this? I think i must create some service with action

`<action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />`

but i do not know how to handle action from physical bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: Unless your app is talking Bluetooth HID to the keyboard -- rather than the system -- then this should not be possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Malware authors would think that it would be *wonderful* to spy on all physical keyboard input.

Comment: but it is possible to create custom software keyboard you can see this example: https://github.com/blackcj/AndroidCustomKeyboard

Comment: Correct. That is an input method editor. It is unrelated to Bluetooth keyboards.

Comment: Thank you very match CommonsWare